# Crystal Field Theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum

I am literally lost with this question:

> Suppose that within the set of (2L+1)(2S+1) lowest-lying ionic states the crystal field can be represented in the form **a(L_x)^2 + b(L_y)^2 + c(L_z)^2**, with a, b, and c all different. Show in the special case L = 1 that if the crystal field is the dominant perturbation (compared with the spin-orbit coupling), then it will yield a (2S+1)-fold degenerate set of ground states in which every matrix element of every component of L vanishes.

Comment: >abuse of the expression "literally"

Comment: Point taken, but I'm still not sure where to begin.

Comment: Does the $L$ in your form of the crystal field correspond to the angular momentum operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The physical context would have been helpful. I am guessing that this is some sort of once ionized atom, whose electron is in an L=1 state, sitting inside an atomic crystal, which breaks the rotational symmetry by the crystal axes.

First, the S is a decoupled electron spin, which is completely irrelevant. You can ignore the 2S+1 factors and all the misdirecting jawboning about spin in the question. This is a reformulation:

You have a quantum mechanical system with angular momentum 1. This means that there are 3 different rotated versions of the state, with $L_z=-1,0,+1$, which have exactly the same energy, they are degenerate, because the world is rotationally invariant.

Now you put this system inside a crystal that breaks the rotational symmetry, and the leading perturbation from the crystal *between these three states and no other*, is

$$ a L_x^2 + b L_y^2 + cL_z^2 $$

The operators $L_x$,$L_y$ and $L_z$ are specific 3 by 3 matrices acting on these three states. You probably were given their form from the raising and lowering operators for z-angular momentum: $L_x - iL_y$, $L_x + iL_y$.

- Find the new ground state,
- show that all the "matrix elements" of each component of L vanish in this ground state.

The first part is easy diagonalization of the 3 by 3 matrix given to you above. This is clearly a homework exercize, so you should do it yourself. It is straightforward.

The second depends on the intended interpretation of the word "matrix elements": after comments by jojo, I learn that the "matrix elements" are just supposed to be the expected value of the $L_x$, $L_y$ an $L_z$ between the ground state copies with different spin. This is a terrible abuse of the term "matrix elements", because these matrix elements are just the expectation value of $L_x$,$L_y$ and $L_z$ in the ground state, the spin is completely decoupled. So all you need to show is that the expected value of $L_x$,$L_y$ and $L_z$ are zero.

I misinterpreted the wording initially to mean something impossible, namely:

- Show that the matrix elements between the ground states and the other $L_z$ states are all zero, for each of the three operators $L_x,L_y,L_z$.

There are no states of L=1 system for which the matrix elements of each component of L vanishes. Such a state would be a rotationally invariant vector, which does not exist--- the only rotationally invariant objects are scalars.

Because the actual wording is potentially misleading, this problem is not very good. It is better to say explicitly: "Show that all the matrix elements between the components of L between the different ground states is zero."

Comment: There is no error. Since the ground state is not degenerate, what needs to vanish is the expectation value of the different components of L over a single state.  This does not require rotational symmetry of this state at all. For example, think of the Lz=0 state.

Comment: @jojo: that was the intended answer, you gave it away (you have to choose the z axis wisely though). The problem is that the $L_x$ and $L_y$ operators have nonzero matrix elements between the $L_z=0$ state at $L_z=\pm 1$ states. The question wasn't asking about zero expecation value, which indeed holds, but zero matrix elements, which cannot be done.

Comment: I wasn't giving away the answer. Look a set of states with different quantum numbers n , some angular momentum L^2 and Lz=0. In this subspace all of the matrix element of Lx, Ly, Lz are zero. Therefore there is no error is the question.

Comment: @jojo: this subspace is 1 dimensional--- there are no matrix elements, only the single expectation value. When someone says "the matrix elements are zero" they usually mean between two different states. It is possible that the question meant expectation value, but this is a grossly misleading way to phrase it, and it is trivial in this way of thinking. The slightly nontrivial fact is that $L_x^2$ and $L_y^2$ have zero matrix elements between the $L_z=0$ state and the $L_x=\pm 1$ states, and I believe this is the intended question. We agree on the content, though, so no need to bicker.

Comment: The space is not 1 dimensional, because of this n. But never mind. In any case there is nothing wrong with the existence of a "(2S+1)-fold degenerate set of ground states in which every matrix element of every component of L vanishes.". I have just presented an example of such a set.

Comment: This looks very helpful. I appreciate the effort from both of you guys. If you're interested, it's a problem out of "Solid State Physics" by Ashcroft...a book that's been around for quite a while now, so there is likely no error in the question. All I needed was a way to get started, and this looks like a good starting point, and general guide for the rest of the problem. I appreciate it.

Comment: @Jojo: I see!! The problem is misleadingly worded, because you can completely ignore the spin, so I didn't even see at the spin part when I read it. Because the expected value is zero on the 1d subspace, when you tensor it with the spin, you get "matrix elements", but they are between completely decoupled spins states, so they are completely obviously equal to zero. Thanks for clearing up my confusion.